# Compare two table or insert unique values

Tags: google-bigquery

Dear users of BigQuery.

I've a table with millions of records (table 2) and in this table I've few lost data. So I genrate an other table with all data (table 1).
I need to integrate lost data from table 1 to table 2 or integrate all data of table 1 to table 2 and remove all duplicate records, so I've several ways to do that.

[image]

[image]

What is the best way to do this according to you ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be using UNION DISTINCT .
Your query will look something like :

```
Select name, timestamp, value from Project.Dataset.Table2
UNION DISTINCT
Select name, timestamp, value from Project.Dataset.Table1
```

This should work fine and give you the results.

Comment: Thanks, but with that I only have records not duplicates no ?

Comment: Maybe with EXCEPT DISTINCT I try

Comment: With use of UNION DISTINCT there will be no duplicates in the final result.